# Graph: Attendee automatically accepts event invitation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I wish to add a meeting with attendees into the organizer's calendar, then have the Exchange automatically send meeting invites to attendees. I want the attendees to be able to accept, decline, etc the invite as per the behaviour in Outlook, but my requests currently have the attendee automatically accept the invitation upon adding the event. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Request:

```json
POST /users/{organizer@email.com}/events
{
    "subject": "My Subject",
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2021-10-10T12:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Singapore Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2021-10-10T14:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Singapore Standard Time"
    },
    "responseRequested": true,
    "attendees": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "attendee@email.com",
                "name": "Attendee"
            },
            "type": "required"
        }
    ]
}
```

Response:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(...)/events/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "..."",
    "id": "AAMk...",
    "createdDateTime": "...",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "...",
    "changeKey": "...",
    "categories": [],
    "transactionId": null,
    "originalStartTimeZone": "Singapore Standard Time",
    "originalEndTimeZone": "Singapore Standard Time",
    "iCalUId": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008...",
    "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
    "isReminderOn": true,
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "subject": "My Subject",
    "bodyPreview": "",
    "importance": "normal",
    "sensitivity": "normal",
    "isAllDay": false,
    "isCancelled": false,
    "isOrganizer": true,
    "responseRequested": true,
    "seriesMasterId": null,
    "showAs": "busy",
    "type": "singleInstance",
    "webLink": "...",
    "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
    "isOnlineMeeting": false,
    "onlineMeetingProvider": "unknown",
    "allowNewTimeProposals": true,
    "isDraft": false,
    "hideAttendees": false,
    "recurrence": null,
    "onlineMeeting": null,
    "responseStatus": {
        "response": "organizer",
        "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"><meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Exchange Server\"><!-- converted from text --><style><!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; } --></style></head><body><font size=\"2\"><span style=\"font-size:11pt;\"><div class=\"PlainText\">&nbsp;</div></span></font></body></html>"
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "...",
        "timeZone": "Singapore Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "...",
        "timeZone": "Singapore Standard Time"
    },
    "location": {
        "displayName": "",
        "locationType": "default",
        "uniqueIdType": "unknown",
        "address": {},
        "coordinates": {}
    },
    "locations": [],
    "attendees": [
        {
            "type": "required",
            "status": {
                "response": "none",
                "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Attendee",
                "address": "attendee@email.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "organizer": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Organizer",
            "address": "organizer@email.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can happen in two cases.

Outlook automatically accepts all meeting requests on behalf of groups. You can accept, tentatively accept, or decline meeting requests for user calendars only.

The second case is that user set up Outlook to automatically accept meetings.

Check Outlook->File->Options->Calendar->Automatic accept or decline
[image]